# Yanking text from the previous stdout onto the command line

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, readline

I'd like to set up my Bash in such a way that I could yank text from the previous command's stdout. The example use case I'll use is resolving conflicts during a git rebase.

```
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
# both modified:      app/views/report/index.html.erb
#
$ vim app/views/report/index.html.erb
# .... edit, resolve conflicts ....
$ git add <Alt+.>
```

The problem is that the easiest way to grab the filename for the 2nd command (`vim ...`) is to move my hand over to the mouse. One option is `screen`, but that has its own set of issues as a day-to-day shell. (Not the least of which is that I use and abuse Ctrl+A as a readline shortcut)

Where could I start at making this work for me? Ideally I'd like to be able to pull the *N*th line from the stdout of the previous command somewhere that I can manipulate it as a command.

Comment: This is old, but I found myself in a similar situation. You can use history -s "$command" and right after that use up key to recall. Or you can take a look at how `fzf` does it with the keybindings to `__fzf_history__` (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using the mouse, the only way I can think of is to use `grep`, `sed` and/or `awk`, perhaps with `tee` and/or a Bash function and process substitution and/or process and/or command substitution:

```
vim $(git status | tee /dev/tty | grep ...)
```

or

```
var=$(git status | tee /dev/tty | grep ...)
vim "$var"
git add "$var"
```

The `tee` allows you to see the full output while capturing the modified output. Creating a function would allow you to easily pass an argument that would select a certain line:

```
var=$(some_func 14)
etc.
```

The disadvantage is that you have to do this from the start. I don't know of any way to do this after the fact without using `screen` or some other output logging and scripting a rummage through the log.

Comment: Yeah, it's becoming obvious that I'll need to modify my environment to capture stdout/stderr and then write something to pull those lines in. Your suggestions look good, but I'm not sure how I'd get this from a variable onto the bash command line (i.e. expand the variable inline, or even better, do all this from a shortcut key)

Comment: @Shaun: Do you really need to expand it? Can't you just reference the variable as in my example? You can press Ctrl-Alt-e to expand the variable on the command line if you need to (it will do other expansions at the same time). Search for "shell-expand-line" in `man bash` for more information. Unfortunately, readline functions can't be called programmatically.

Comment: That's unfortunate - it's more effort than just using the mouse to do it. I was hoping I'd be able to code my way around it, but it looks like that's not really an option without modifying Bash. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a good, clean solution, but as a hack you could try the `script` command, which logs all input and output to a file.  For GNU `script`:

```
$ script -f
Script started, file is typescript
$ ls -1
bar
baz
foo
typescript
$ echo $(tail -3 typescript | head -1)
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

pipe the output through sed:

```
git status | sed -n '5p'
```

to get the 5th line